# Buscar conjunto de registros por data

Tags: java, mysql

Atualmente estou criando um programa Java/Mysql Desktop.
Ao inserir no banco, a tabela está bem simples:

```
id - dataInserido - códigoProduto - qtd
```

Eu gostaria, por meio de um SQL, agrupar em ordem decrescente os últimos registros inseridos na mesma data. 
Exemplo: tenho atabela de produtos inseridos

```
id - data - produto - qtd  
1 - 20/05/2017 - 10001 - 100  
1 - 24/05/2017 - 10002 - 10  
1 - 27/05/2017 - 100010 - 30  
1 - 29/05/2017 - 100020 - 60  
1 - 29/05/2017 - 100060 - 70  
1 - 29/05/2017 - 100010 - 100
```

Como agrupar os últimos (29/05/2017), sendo 100020, 100060 e 100010, uma vez que tenho que montar essa tabela no Java ? Uma espécie de filtro solicitado pelo usuário.

ps: eu não desejo levar nenhuma data pelo java, mas sim uma consulta pelo próprio sql.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo da saída que você deseja

Comment: Se entendi sua pergunta (pois não sou tão bom assim em Java ainda), sempre realizo isso:
while (rs.next()) {
                Lista.add(new Object[]{rs.getInt("id")});
            }
Ainda não defini como seria a saida e como vou pegar os valores no Java. Se também puder sugerir algo, agradeço. Apareceu agora esse desafio, desde quando comecei

Comment: Um simples `SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY dataInserido DESC` não resolveria?

Comment: Não muito. O banco pegaria todos os registros e ordenaria. Eu gostaria somente da ultima data dos produtos registrados.

Comment: Ou se quisesse trazer os registro somente somente no dia atual: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dataInserido = CURDATE()`

Comment: Obrigado. Será útil sua sugestão para o filtro "Lançados Hoje" que estou fazendo também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é filtrar pela coluna `data` utilizando a cláusula `WHERE` com `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.data,
       t.produto,
       t.qtd
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela t2
                   WHERE t2.data > t.data)
 ORDER BY t.produto DESC
```

A cláusula `ORDER BY` irá ordenar os registros de acordo com a coluna que foi especificada.

Note que respeitei o nome das colunas dado no exemplo e não na sua descrição.

Comment: Dessa forma como mencionou eu teria que levar uma data do Java para o Mysql, não seria ?
A tabela é preenchida diariamente e sempre terá produtos, data, e qtd lançados diariamente.
Da forma como estou construindo o usuário escolhe no ComboBox a opção "Filtrar Data Mais Recente" e essa ação traz para a tabela os produtos do ultimo lançamento. SELECT cód, qtd, data FROM controle_diario GROUP BY data ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1;
Não é tão adequado, ele pega uma ultima data, porém um único ultimo registro aleatório

Comment: @rafB alterei para mostrar todos os registros da última data

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado Sorack. Problema resolvido dessa forma como fez.